# Native Salesforce App vs Decoupled Angular Application with Salesforce API backend

Tags: angular, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am working with a potential client and they keep waffling back and forth between building a native Salesforce app or letting me use my preferred front-end technology, Angular.

I am not very familiar with Salesforce, so if anyone could provide some insight for me, I would be very grateful!

Basically, I believe that building the front-end with Angular and using the Salesforce API for the backend is a great solution that would work really well. (They already use salesforce as their CMS and do not want to change that, which is fine with me.)

As far as I can tell, there is no benefit to building the app directly into Salesforce except that if I built it with Lightning, non-code users could edit the project. Is this interpretation correct? Am I missing something? Can anyone explain why a native Salesforce app would be a better choice?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the audience for the app - are they Salesforce users, external users, a mix? What is the data store; is it all in Salesforce?

Comment: The audience is all external. The data store is all in salesforce.

Comment: Is the audience authenticated and do they have different data visibility requirements per user or partner?

Comment: We would need authenticated users. I was under the impression I could do this with the Salesforce API? Or is it a different type of authentication system? Our data expert has also brought up the option to set up our own API and backend and simply regular import and update the appropriate data from salesforce as necessary.